# Using Workflow Variables in Session Properties

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a scenario where my source file name will be coming from one db table I have to read that value and pass it in the value of Source File Name in Session properties.

Till now I have tried like I have created 2 sessions where the 1st session will read the db table where the source file name is stored and store it in one mapping variable and in post success variable assignment I am assigning the mapping variable value to workflow variable and in the next main session I am trying to give the workflow variable in the session file name attribute .

But it is showing error like below

fail to expand variables in file field [$$WL_File].

How can I achieve this.

Please suggest some ideas.

Comment: An alternative approach is to create a flat file containing your source filename(s) in the first session. Then in the second session use that file as indirect source file.

Answer (score 0):

In Target definition, on Columns tab you can click the "Add FileName column to this table". Then in the mapping whatever you'll pass to this port will be used as the file name, instead of the file name defined in session properties.
Creating multiple output files is a bit more tricky and will require Transaction Control to tell when one file is completed.